# How to add a down block for Sequel add_unique_constraint migration

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a Sequel migration in PostgreSQL, which works up, but not down:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    alter_table(:files) do
      add_unique_constraint [:name, :folder]
    end
  end
end
```

When trying to migrate down from this block, Sequel's error message says this is an "irreversible migration" and suggests writing my "own down method".

How do I write the down method for this particular migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/schema_modification.rdoc#drop_constraint):

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    alter_table(:files) do
      add_unique_constraint [:name, :folder]
    end
  end

  down do
    alter_table(:files) do
      drop_constraint(:your_constraint_name, :type=>:unique)
    end
  end
end
```

You will have to figure out the name of your uniqueness constraint. It should appear in your schema, and it should be something like `index_files_on_name_and_folder`.

Comment: Thank you! The name of the unique constraint I did not understand. But another question: I probably should name the unique constraint myself, so that it will be same in all environments? There's some info on the same docs you linked.

Comment: This seems to work on the up block: "add_unique_constraint [:name, :folder], :unique_constraint_name => "files_name_folder_key"